# Question won't appear in network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, top-questions

Four days ago I asked a question here on MSO and it received 20> votes. However, it won't appear in my network profile, while other answers and questions do. I thought it was cached or something so I did a few hard refreshes and waited a few days before I decided to post this report. I can't see why it does not show up. It is not CW.

**Edit:**

From what I can tell, this is not [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Can this be traced down to a single problem? Could a mod fix this, or would it have to be a dev?

**Edit-2:**

I've now noticed that my accept rate is 75%. However, I've accepted 4 out of 5 answers. So, obviously, one is not counting towards the title. I think (but don't know) that the one not counting towards my accept rate is the one not showing up in my network profile. Is this somehow related?

Comment: Is it this question? Link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143154/site-currently-in-read-only-mode

Comment: Precisely. Is there something different about it?

Comment: Interesting - I checked my own profile, and one of my meta question appears in my top questions list.

Comment: I also have multiple MSO questions in [my network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1119942/luke).

Comment: Could a mod mark this as [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)? Not sure if it was fixed purposely or what, but the question show up in my network profile just fine now.

Comment: @Kevin was this a bug?

Comment: @Kevin, I face the same pblm, see my [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166446/why-does-the-sync-with-my-so-profile-not-work-properly-in-se)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some unusual things happened to that question of yours:

1. You deleted it minute after posting then undeleted 12 seconds later.
2. Your question was the destination of a merge 20 minutes later.

It's all visible in the [revisions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/143154/revisions), I assume one of those things caused the question to vanish from the "central" database or whatever holding the data for our network profiles.

Comment: Hmm. It could be. I deleted it because at first I thought someone had beaten me to asking it and I didn't want it closed; then I realized mine was first and un-deleted it.

Comment: Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Luke dunno, can't know for sure what happened need mod or dev. :)

Comment: It's fixed now. I wonder what happened.