# Why does the sync with my SO profile not work properly in SE?

Tags: bug, network-profile, top-questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441534/ios-how-to-set-font-when-drawing-text-in-pdf-generation) which received 6 upvotes, and should be in the list of top questions in my Stack Exchange [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/394477/nazik).

It didn't show up. Why? Is there any specific reason for that? Or will the sync process take some time?

Comment: the qn is now with 5 upvotes,it got a downvote after this post, but still it is eligible as a top question

Comment: Caching....[the answer is always caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166393/why-cant-i-get-on-chat/166394#comment486989_166394).

Comment: @Bart two weeks cache? Hard to believe..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, that's the same doubt for me, I waited a lot!

Comment: I noticed in the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14441534/revisions) that you deleted your own question shortly after posting then undeleted. This might have caused the problem as also mentioned in [this other report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143672/question-wont-appear-in-network-profile). Kevin never responded so don't know what he fixed though.

Comment: nice,that's the reason I needed, this must be an answer

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, then, what should I do to make my questn in that list?

Comment: Dunno, maybe try adding your own comment on the question I linked to notifying Kevin it happened to you too. I'm not sure that's the reason just yet (unless a dev confirms it).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah, hadn't realized that it has been two weeks.

Comment: @Bart another reason: Oscillation. :-P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, Oscillation means?

Comment: I posted a comment in the question that u linked for Kevin's view

Comment: @Azik private Meta joke. If you're interested, it started [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166098/152859).