# Question not appearing on network profile (probably due to account merging)

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18294872/2041954) with 30+ upvotes on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2041954/archy-holt) is not appearing in my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1340453/archy-holt?tab=accounts). (My answer to it was there though.) Apparently something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143672/question-wont-appear-in-network-profile) happened again and I think it was because the question was asked by my merged account (I merged my newly created account with my actual account within one, two days after asking the question).

> It showed that I only had 1 questions in my SE profile.
>
> [image: showing only 1 question]
>
> [The question "iOS 7 Status Bar Back to iOS 6 style?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18294872/2041954) wasn't listed as top question.
>
> [image]
>
> It is not missing in my SO profile though.
>
> [image: 2 questions]

What should I do to fix it?

I really want that question of mine to show up in my network profile.

Comment: Just to say that we are aware of this and have not forgotten you. There is some maintenance work scheduled for the weekend which might just fix this.

Comment: @Oded Just to let you guys know that I really appreciate that! Thanks a lot! Take your time! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That took a while!

We did some work on our Oregon data center, meaning that there were some reindexing jobs waiting for that work to finish (uptime is important to us!).

This happened earlier today and as you can see in your profile page, all appears as it should be.

Comment: You're starting to sound more and more like Nick... and that's a good thing! :-)

Comment: It looks like the issue is resolved for the OP. But on my side I still have a similar issue. How can I force a refresh of the data in the network profile?